# Cron job for /_ah/xmpp/message/chat/

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cron

I'm trying to create a jabber bot which has to perform an action every 5 minutes.
So he has a doGet method, and there is a cron.xml which triggers a servlet at the path `<url>/_ah/xmpp/message/chat/</url>`

But in my Web Admin Panel I see that cron task never succeeds.

```
/_ah/xmpp/message/chat/   every 5 minutes (UTC) 
Pinging                   2011/02/11 04:21:40 on time Failed
```

So is it restriced by GAE, and **/_ah/xmpp/message/chat/** cannot be triggered by Cron?
Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The URL "/_ah/xmpp/message/chat/" responds to POST request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/_ah/xmpp/message/chat/` is the URL that *receives* messages, so pinging this URL in a cron job would simulate *receiving* an XMPP message, and may be disabled for this use case as a result.

If you want to *send* an XMPP message every 5 minutes, you can do that in a regular handler that calls `xmppService.sendMessage()`.

If you want to simulate *receiving* an XMPP message every 5 minutes, you can handle message reception in a regular handler and have your real XMPP handler call that handler when a message is received.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say something without any details.

I'd recommend to:

1. Take a look at Logs in application control panel
2. Ensure, that war.xml has correct description of your servlet
3. Test your service by opening URL of your application with browser or CURL - either on test server, or on GAE infrastructure.